# MongoEngine, reference to parent in EmbeddedDocument

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using MongoEngine and defined Documents with embeddeddocuments. It would be very handy to have a direct reference to the parent of this embeddeddocument. However I couldn't find any documentation about this.

```
@standard_updates.apply
class Crud(EmbeddedDocument, GeneralMixin):
    collectionName = StringField(required=True)
    create = BooleanField()
    read = BooleanField()
    update = BooleanField()
    delete = BooleanField()
    mutdat = DateTimeField()


@standard_updates.apply
class Group(Document, GeneralMixin):
    description = StringField()
    allowedfunctions = ListField()
    cruds = EmbeddedDocumentListField(Crud)
    mutdat = DateTimeField()
```

This is a trivial example. But suppose I have a Crud object which I have read from Mongo (by retrieving a Group object), now I do not have the Group object anymore (for whatever reason), but I need to update the Crud object, then it is a pain to get the original Group object back, so that it can be updated. I think it would be very easy to have a reference to the original Group object so that one can easily retrieve the "parent" object.

Comment: can you post some code showing your structure and desired functionality?

Comment: I answer my own question. There is a weakref to _instance in the object that is retrieved. This is a reference to the parent object. This is exactly what I need. Problem is however that the _ indicates that it is an internal field and not supposed to be used outside the object. And als subject to change without notice.....

Comment: Helas, this was not the solution, because it is a weakref, the object is deleted before I can use it.....